# Accessibility - Bootstrap4 Carousel control tabbing is not going on to carousel-caption div while using the tab key from Keyboard

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-carousel

PFB is the example, Here I am using for Bootstrap Carousel control.

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_carousel2&stacked=h

This example is working fine but when i am using tab key from the keyboard, control is not going on to anchor tag inside the div with class "carousel-caption".

I tried "tab-index" attribute for anchor tag to set the tabbing but tabbing is not working properly.

I want tabbing to work like below:

- Left Arrow -> 1st anchor tag("LA is always so much fun!") -> 2nd anchor tag("Thank you, Chicago!") -> 3rd anchor tag("We love the Big Apple!") -> Right arrow

Could anyone please let me know how to implement tabbing for

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="C:\Users\user1\Desktop\Sample\video-bg-static1.png" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>Los Angeles</h3>
                <a>LA is always so much fun!</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <img src="C:\Users\user1\Desktop\Sample\video-bg-static2.png" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>Chicago</h3>
                <a>Thank you, Chicago!</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <img src="C:\Users\user1\Desktop\Sample\video-bg-static3.png" alt="New york" style="width:100%;">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>New York</h3>
                <a>We love the Big Apple!</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have tab index defined on an `<li>`, so we had to wrap our `ul.carousel-indicators>li` inside an anchor tag (which does work with tab index)...

Check the code which works with the same example and implements tabIndex as you wanted...

**update**: in light of questioner's comment, tab index now goes to the `<p>` under the heading on each slide instead of the carousel indicators; the href for these `<a>` tags to be updated by the user...

```css
.carousel-indicators .active {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <h2>Carousel Example</h2>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">

      <div class="item active">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Los Angeles</h3>
          <a class="active" tabindex="2" href="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0">
            <p>LA is always so much fun!</p>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Chicago</h3>
          <a class="" tabindex="3" href="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1">
            <p>Thank you, Chicago!</p>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/ny.jpg" alt="New York" style="width:100%;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>New York</h3>
          <a class="" tabindex="4" href="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2">
            <p>We love the Big Apple!</p>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li class="" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0">
      </li>
      <li class="" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1">
      </li>
      <li class="" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2">
      </li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" tabindex="1" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>

    <a class="right carousel-control" tabindex="5" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Akber thanks for your quick reply.  As per your answer, control is going on to carousel indicators(dots below the carousel control) but i want the control goes on to the anchor tag(in this example, anchor tag of "LA is always so much fun!") in carousel caption. Can you please suggest me on this.

Comment: @Avinash, Kindly check now

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment:

> ...Here I want to navigate between the carousel controls using the keyboard.

You can use [keydown event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keydown_event). As reported in the documentation:

> Keyboard events are only generated by ,  and anything with the contentEditable attribute or with tabindex="-1".

It's required to add **tabindex="-1"** to your carousel div plus the event handler.

```js
$('#myCarousel').on('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 37) {  // left arrow
        $('#myCarousel').carousel('prev')
    } else {
        if (e.keyCode == 39) {  // right arrow
            $('#myCarousel').carousel('next')
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" tabindex="-1">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff&text=1" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">

                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>Los Angeles</h3>
                    <a>LA is always so much fun!</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff&text=2" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">

                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>Chicago</h3>
                    <a>Thank you, Chicago!</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff&text=3" alt="New york" style="width:100%;">

                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>New York</h3>
                    <a>We love the Big Apple!</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Left and right controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. Here I want to navigate between the carousel controls using the keyboard. please let me know if you have any idea on this